# The SDK directory 'C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' does not exist

Tags: react-native

Could somebody help me fix this problem?
When I run react-native run-android in CMD Windows OS, I got this error.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   The SDK directory 'C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' does not exist.

I searched everything to fix it but not successful.

1. I created local.properties in android dir and add this: `sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\ABC\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk`
2. Create ANDROID_HOME variable: `C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` and add to path: ...%ANDROID_HOME%platforms;%ANDROID_HOME%platform-tools
   but no luck.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also set android path from CMD.

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Note: You have to run these two commands every time you open new instance of your CMD

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. But after that I run react-native run-android, I got this new error:
Could not create ADB bridge. ADB location ...\platform-tools\adb.exe.

I added path of sdk to Gennymotion but when I start VM again, it didn't run, and a command line window display many times. Do you have any solution?

Comment: In new CMD window inside your project directory run command: npm start

Comment: Thanks for your help but nothing happend. After run command: npm start, I run react-native run-android in CMD window before. However there a cmd appear then disappear immediately. I still got the same error: Could not adb bridge. do you have any solution?

Comment: Please add screenshot to your question.

Comment: I solved my problems. I uninstalled nodejs and all related packages in AppData\Roaming\npm directory and then installed them again. Finally run command lines as you mention above. Everything is fine. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same error even after configuring the environment variables like the above answer, Check the local.properties file. Most probably there can be different ANDROID_HOME path.

[local.properties file located in the android folder of the react native code base.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc2wY.png)

Answer (score 0):

After installing of Android studio you need run it first and create your device. (i don't remember how but it helped for me)Untill this done you not have android folder. To watch my suggestion open C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local
and go to your Local folder
mark 'View/show-hide/hidden items' in as on the pictures. 
Then open android studio, and create android device.And you will see how hidden android folder have appeared(can be seen if hidden items marked)